# rails getting count of rows per user per date in activerecord sqlite

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I'm starting out with an Activities table that looks like the one below and I'd like to get a count for activities per user per month. The issue is right now, there are multiple rows per day for each user. I need to count only one row per day for each user.

```
Activities

Activity_id  |   user_id |  activity_type |  created_at

1                  1          time_trial        2016-04-30
2                  1          time_trial        2016-04-30
3                  1          time_trial        2016-04-31
4                  3          time_trial        2016-04-31
5                  3          time_trial        2016-04-31
6                  1          time_trial        2016-04-32
```

I figure the resulting table should something like

```
user_id  |   activities per month

1                  3
3                  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [the ActiveRecord `group` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).

Your query will look something like:

```
Activity.where(user_id: 1).group("date(created_at)").count
```

...to get "A count of User 1's days with at least one activity."

If you want to get it month-by-month, [use ActiveRecord range conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions). (You'll need to scroll down to section 2.3.2)

```
Activity.where(user_id: 1).where(created_at: (1.month.ago..Time.now)).group("date(created_at)").count
```

...to get "A count of User 1's days with at least one activity in the past month."

I'm not going to go through all the possible permutations of months and counting. Hopefully this gets you started! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
Activity.where(:user_id=>user.id).group_by { |data| data.created_at).to_date }
```